# x and y coordinates of image in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, coordinates, android-image

How to getthe  X and y coordinates of an image in Layout in Android?
And how to get top, bottom, left and right of an image in Layout in Android?

Comment: you want co-ordinates on `onClick()` event of image?

Answer (score 0):

by using `Touch listeners` you can get X and Y values of `view`

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {           
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: the question was about the position of the view, not the touch event.

Comment: ohh sorry for irrelevant answer, i thank like that, but it not.

Answer (score 0):

for x and y coordinates of any view compared to its parents , use :
`getLeft()` , `getTop()` ,  `getRight()` ,and `getBottom()` .

for raw x and y coordinates of any view compared to the screen/window , use:
`getLocationInWindow(int[] location)` , `getLocationOnScreen(int[] location)`

do note that all of those methods won't work till the view is positioned and layout procedure has finished.

more methods are written on the API [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Comment: I need some assistance with mine... Can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370470/how-to-fix-dragging-outside-of-the-layout-and-near-the-edge-fcing-the-app